# D3 nested group as x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I use a nested group in D3 as my x-axis?  Is it at all possible.

I am not on my dev machine to post my code example, but for illustrative purposes, let's assume the following code from: [What is the best way to form age groups from a list in D3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479917/what-is-the-best-way-to-form-age-groups-from-a-list-in-d3)

```
var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.sex; })
    .key(function(d){
      var ageGroup = null;
      if (d.age <= 10){
        ageGroup = '0-10';
      } else if (d.age > 10 && d.age <= 20 ){
        ageGroup = '10-20';
      } else if (d.age > 20 && d.age <= 30 ){
        ageGroup = '20-30';
      } else if (d.age > 30 && d.age <= 40 ){
        ageGroup = '30-40';
      } else if (d.age > 40 && d.age <= 50 ){
        ageGroup = '40-50';
      } else if (d.age > 50 && d.age <= 60 ){
        ageGroup = '50-60';
      } else if (d.age > 60 && d.age <= 70 ){
        ageGroup = '60-70';
      } else if (d.age > 70 && d.age <= 80 ){
        ageGroup = '70-80';
      } else if (d.age > 80 && d.age <= 90 ){
        ageGroup = '80-90';
      } else if (d.age > 90 && d.age <= 100 ){
        ageGroup = '90-100';
      }
      return ageGroup;
    })
    .entries(myArray);
```

How would I use `ageGroup` as my x-axis?

Comment: you can use it as ordinal scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grouped bar charts to display your data. As @Cyril commented you can use ordinal scales to position your axis values and data.

I created a simple jsFiddle to show my approach.

```
var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1); // x scale for your ageRanges

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal(); // Inner x scale for your Male and Female values.

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]); // y sale for your count value

var color = d3.scale.ordinal() // set colors for inner x scale
.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
```

Here is the jsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/rnoo6buy/

Comment: Thanks @torresomar. What if I wanted to show the gender as stacked? e.g. Male at y0 and Female at y1?

Comment: You can handle that by following this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

Comment: Thanks @torresomar. Yes, I know of this example however, I have to try and map between the data array and the nest array. The example does not do this.

Comment: do you have any ideas?